# How to select rows that contain only values from a group

Tags: sql

I have several office ids and several zip codes

```
Office id   Zip Code
1111111        45220
1111111        45221
1111111        45214
1111111        45215
1111111        45216
1111112        45220
1111112        45221
1111112        45214
1111113        45220
1111113        45221
1111113        45214
1111113        45215
```

my condition is select office id, which is located only in  zip codes 45220, 45221 and 45214.  and the office id shall not contain any other zip codes.  in above table, id 1111112 only shall be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  These are really helpful.  I have several zip codes in the list.  so I updated my query without including "count = 3" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be like this :

```
    SELECT  a.office_id  
    FROM    mytable a
            INNER JOIN mytable b
                ON a.office_id = b.office_id 
    WHERE   b.zip_code IN (45220,45221,45214)
AND a.office_id not in 
(
    select office_id from mytable c
    where c.zip_code NOT IN (45220, 45221, 45214)
)
    GROUP BY a.office_id  
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery and join like so:

```
SELECT office_id
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT office_id
  FROM your_table
  WHERE zip_code IN (45220,45221,45214)
  GROUP BY office_id
  HAVING COUNT(zip_code) = 3
  ) t2
ON t1.office_id = t2.office_id
GROUP BY office_id
HAVING COUNT(zip_code) = 3;
```

You can also use set operation `except` like this:

```
  SELECT office_id
  FROM your_table
  WHERE zip_code IN (45220,45221,45214)
  GROUP BY office_id
  HAVING COUNT(zip_code) = 3
  EXCEPT
  SELECT office_id
  FROM your_table
  WHERE zip_code NOT IN (45220,45221,45214);
```

Comment: `except` is SQL standard, while `minus` is not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated. Thanks. I just mentioned both as OP didn't mentioned the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select office_id from mytable where zip_code in(45220,45221,45214) group by office_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct office from Locations
where office NOT IN 
(
    select office from Locations
    where zip NOT IN (45220, 45221, 45214)
)
and zip IN (45220, 45221, 45214)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that avoids multiple sub-queries and only requires a single scan over the table which might be faster depending on the DBMS being used.

```
select office_id
from office
group by office_id
having min(case when zip_code in ('45220', '45221', '45214') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and count(case when zip_code in ('45220', '45221', '45214') then 1 end) = 3;
```

The expression `case when zip_code in ('45220', '45221', '45214') then 1 else 0 end` will evaluate to 0 if any other zip_code is present. So that filters out all offices with more then those three zip codes.

The `count(...)` then makes sure that the office does not have fewer then those three zip codes.

---

If you are using Postgres, you can also use an array aggregation to simplify the code:

```
select office_id
from office
group by office_id
having array_agg(zip_code order by zip_code) = array['45214', '45220', '45221']
```

Note the the array elements must be in the same order `['45214', '45220', '45221']` is a different array then `['45220', '45214', '45221']`